# How to stop opening multiple tabs in Google Chrome using accessibility service

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, accessibility

I am using this code in my accessibility service to search anything on Google. It will be searched by safe search, but I am getting a problem that it is searching the keyword. Foe example, “YouTube on Google” safe search. The problem is that it is opening multiple tabs. How do I resolve this?

```
private fun checkSafeSearchToggle() {
        val rootNodeInfo = rootInActiveWindow
        val list =
            rootNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar")
        for (node in list) {
            if (node != null) {
                if (node.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {

                    Log.e("sf", "node:${node.text.toString()}")
                       val data=MyUtils.appendUri(node.text.toString(),"safe=active")
                    Log.e("sf","appendedUri:$data")
                    val row = web_History.getStatus()
                    if (row != null) {
                        val rowId = row.id
                        val rowStatus = row.status
                        Log.e("sf", "dbRow:$rowId:$rowStatus")
                        if (rowStatus == "true") {

                            if (node.text.toString().contains( "google.com")) {

                                try {
                                    val qData = node.text.toString()
                                    Log.e("sf", "nodeData:$qData")

                                    val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                    sharingIntent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.$data")
                                    startActivity(sharingIntent)
                                }
                                catch (ex:Error)
                                {
                                 Log.e("sf","Error:$ex")
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            if (node.text.toString() == "https://www.google.com/?safe=active") {
                                val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                                sharingIntent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/")
                                startActivity(sharingIntent)
                            } 
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think opening a new tab for each incoming link is the default behavior for Google Chrome. Have you tried modifying the new tab behavior in Google Chrome?

Comment: yes but not working